# Remove white space and special characters in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String which contains some special characters and white spaces as well. I want to remove white spaces and special character. I am doing it as:

```
String str = "45,%$^ Sharma%$&^,is,46&* a$# Java#$43 Developer$#$^ in#$^ CST&^* web*&(,but he%^&^% wants to move@!$@# to another team";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

Output:

```
sharma is a Java Developer in CST web but he wants to move to another team
```

Can I do this using single operation? How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace special characters in string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608205/replace-special-characters-in-string-in-java)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace any sequence of non-letters with a single white space:

```
str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ")
```

You also might want to apply [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) after the replace.

If you want to support languages other than English, use `"[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}]+"` or `"[^\\p{IsLetter}]+"`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304804/what-is-the-difference-between-character-isalphabetic-and-character-isletter-in) about the differences.

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem of reducing the spaces to one signle space. "# " should be replaced by " ", not 2 spaces.

Comment: Nevermind, I had been misleaded by the previous post including \\s, forgetting the negation included the spaces ^^

Comment: I was about to write the same answer. Working code here: http://ideone.com/QbszDu

Comment: I am not able to understand the "+" in the  [^a-zA-Z]+. please explain the work of plus(+).

Comment: In [regexes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `+` is a quantifier that means that the pattern is repeated one or more times. (`*` means any number of times, including zero; `?` means optional)

Comment: thanks Arian,I know that but here i am not able to recognize how it is removing spaces.

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z]` matches any character that is not a letter, including spaces. The `+` makes that that the hole sequence is matched at once (Look [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=[^a-zA-Z]%2B&input=45%2C%25%24^%20Sharma%25%24%26^%2Cis%2C46%26*%20a%24%23%20java%23%2443%20Developer%24%23%24^%20in%23%24^%20CST%26^*%20web*%26%28%2Cbut%20He%25^%26^%25%20want%20to%20move%40!%24%40%23%20in%20another%20team) for a visualization). The sequence is then replaced with a single space.

Comment: he did not asked even a single space, why are you adding single space. It should be str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "")

Answer (score 4):

The OR operator (`|`) should work:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z]|\\s)+", " "));
```

Actually, the space doesn't have to be there at all:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", " "));
```

Comment: @Dev are your sure you added the `(` and `)` in the regex as shown above?  This solution works!

Comment: I think you should accept @Arian 's answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
str.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}\\s\\d]+", " ");
```

Replacing punctuation, digits and white spaces with a single space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to remove anything that is not a character (A-Z or a-z).

```
str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```