# How to get position of the first letter in a string

Tags: java, regex

I need to get position of the first letter in a string.

Follow a basic example. The first letter is `T`, So I need to know the position of `T`, for that I can use `indexOf("T")`.

I would like to get the first letter by regex instead to add the letter hard-coded (`T`).

Thanks in advance.

```
public class RegexMatches {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String line = "000 1 This is my message";
        int first = line.indexOf("T");
        line = line.substring(first, line.length());

        System.out.println(line);
     }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: method to get position of a match in a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615749/java-method-to-get-position-of-a-match-in-a-string)

Comment: @Robin: But that question doesn't consider regex matches, does it?

Comment: The indexOf can't receive "T" because it's a example, if the message starts with other letter it will not works.

Comment: @Mena please undelete your answer. It was basically correct, just don't read the group but the start index.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: my bad, should have linked to that one: [Java: method to get position of a match in a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938498/get-the-index-of-a-pattern-in-a-string-using-regex)

Comment: @Thomas: I think Tim's answer is correct.

Comment: @BheshGurung yes, but Mena's is also correct with the minor change suggested. (And he was first to answer ;) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I read the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start%28%29) correctly, you're looking for the `start` method of the match object:

```
String line = "000 1 This is my message";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.start());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If, as I interpret, you're looking for the first alphabetic character in a sentence or its index through regular expressions, here's an example:

```
String line = "000 1 This is my message";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
    System.out.println("At: " + m.start());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: T
At: 6
```

Comment: This doesn't work for non-english alphabets.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need `regex` you can do it just by looping through (My reccomendation)

```
public int findFirstLetterPosition(String input) {
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        c = input.charAt(i);
        if ( (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' || c <= 'Z') ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // not found
}
```

**EDIT**

In response to some comments, you could also do this less explicitly using a built in static method, and add some handling for non-ASCII characters using `isLetter`:

```
public int findFirstLetterPosition(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i))) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // not found
}
```

You can also use `isAlphabetic`:

```
public int findFirstLetterPosition(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(input.charAt(i))) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // not found
}
```

The latter includes some alphabetic characters from other languages which are *iffy* on whether to box them as [characters or phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304804/what-is-the-difference-between-character-isalphabetic-and-character-isletter-in)

ref: [`Character.isLetter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-int-), [`Character.isAlphabetic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic-int-)

Comment: What would you do for non-ASCII characters?

Comment: Why not `if (Character.isLetter(c))`?